# Shader Graph - Is recompilation of a shader for each change a good idea?

Tags: c++, shader

I am writing a Shader Graph for my engineering thesis. I'm kinda stuck on whether I should recompile the shader each time some pin value changes to get a real-time preview result or maybe there's a better way to handle this.

Let's consider this screenshot:
[image]

For simplicity a fragment material has only 2 fields - base color and alpha.

the generated code of this graph looks like this:

```c
void FragmentShader(out FragmentMaterial material)
{
    vec3 _Vector3_4302458404873090201 = vec3(0.2, 0.0, 0.0);
    material.baseColor.rgb = _Vector3_4302458404873090201;
    material.baseColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

it's just a simple function that is added to the end of a shader code and gets invoked in a `main` function of a fragment shader.

User can manipulate X, Y and Z values. Each time the value changes the shader is recompiled and cached. Maximum cache size is 50 shaders.

The number of values ​​that can be used is very large. Let's say the user will be sliding the X from 0 to 1 (not too fast) increasing by 0.01. The value is always different, so that's 100 shader recompiles. Only one shader can be recompiled during a frame.

Although I don't see a problem with that, because the shader compilation is fast, I feel like this is not the best option.

Or maybe I'm just tripping and until it won't cause me a performance problem I should stick with it since it's just an editor. I believe the slowest part would be preprocessing and compiling to spirv (which may be kinda slow, I used to use shaderc library), but it will be done when the final values were picked (if they're not in a uniform buffer, but it does not require a shader recompilation).

The editor uses OpenGL so it does not require a shader to be in a spirv format to work.

I don't know. Do you have any ideas, or maybe do you see some problems with this approach, or could suggest what I should do?

Comment: Seems like a job for a uniform shader variable.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you're right. I've got Unity's editor opened and I thought they also recompile a shader (but with different mechanics) for each change. Actually, when I looked closer to the bottom right side, the progress bar of compiling shader shows only one time. It may be stored in some uniform buffer.

Comment: BUT then, let's say there's "Add" node, I would have to do the math on a cpu to pass the add output to the gpu.

Comment: So for a more complex graph, I'd have to traverse all nodes, perform calculations and store the result somewhere. I don't think it will be faster than just recompiling the shader. Plus it's hella more code to write.

Comment: Do you want to have one shader per the whole pipeline or a separate shader for each node?

Comment: Just one shader for the whole pipeline. Maybe in the future for nodes preview, I'd have to have a separate shader for each node. Right now it's just one shader per the whole pipeline, though.

Comment: Maybe you could then recompile the shader after changing of connections only but use an uniform buffer for the tweakable constants. That way the user can change values quickly and only recompile the shader on structural changes.

Comment: That may be the idea. Have an editor-only buffer, generate a uniform variable for each input the node has, and for the final product get rid of this buffer and process the shader graph the way I do it right now

Comment: Alright, you made me thinking the right way, I believe. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Quimby suggested, for previews the shader is recompiled only when connections change.

If an input pin is not connected then it's treated as a uniform variable.

If it's connected, then there has to be a different source (node) that probably has tweakable inputs.

Unless it's a property node that is always treated as a uniform variable and my existing workflow already supports it, so I didn't have to change the way the code is generated by these nodes.